# is there a way to restrict the find to only *.py files

Tags: grep, find

I have the following find command..is there a way to restrict the find to only *.py files?

```
find . | xargs grep 'GIT' -sl
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using `find`, so it's simple. Here's one way:

```
find . -name '*.py' -print | xargs grep 'GIT' -sl {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Most versions of `find` will recognise any wildcards you give them in the `-name` option:

```
find . -name \*.py | xargs grep 'GIT' -sl
```

[Source](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/find1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, u can just use the asterik character (*):

```
find . -name' *.py'
```